# mapping entities with relations backed by obfuscated fields with NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, mapping, obfuscation, deobfuscation

And here goes yet another question on NHibernate.
This one most likely doesn't have a desired answer, but still - let's give it a try.

I'm currently putting all the efforts into mapping a domain model onto the database using NHibernate. This domain model comes from a framework which is heavily obfuscated. (Not that I have worked a lot with obfuscated code before, but this one in most of the places can be translated neither by Reflector, nor by Resharper.)

Everything went more or less fine until I faced an entity with a required many-to-one relationship represented by a property with no setter with obfuscated backed field.

1. Is it possible to reference this obfuscated field somehow? A very special `IPropertyAccessor`?
2. If not, how can I load a fully constructed entity? The only option to inject a related object is by using a constructor that accepts it. But at the time of instantiating of an entity being loaded, neither `IInstantiator` nor `IInterceptor` has any data of it apart from the key. Any other extension points that suit my need?

Answer (score -1):

To allow NHibernate to access your field instead of property you can use this in your mappings:

```
access="field"
```

Comment: NHibernate won't find the field if it's obfuscated.

Comment: True, NHibernate uses `IFieldNameStrategy` to work field name out of the property name.